# How to add a date to next column on multiple condition in google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onEdit() {
  // writes the current date to the cell to the right on the row when a cell in a specific column is edited
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs

  var sheetNameToWatch = "FW21";
  var columnNumberToWatch = /* column S */ 19; // column R = 1, S = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch="Done";

  var columnNumberToWatch = /* column AH */ 34; // not working here.. 
  var valueToWatch="OK Prod";


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var val=sheet.getActiveCell().getValue()

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && val==valueToWatch) {
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()+1
                               );
    targetCell.setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  }
}
```

It only works when i have only one condition for example in col "S" even i create two function it does not work. What am I doing wrong. Please edit the code accordingly. Thanks

And,
How to set up deadlines after 7 Days gap.
Please correct the code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  
  if (sh.getName() == 'FW21') {
    if (e.range.columnStart == 19 && e.value == 'Done') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy") + 7 );}
```

Here is the solution

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  
  if (sh.getName() == 'FW21') {
    if (e.range.columnStart == 19 && e.value == 'Done') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() + ( 3600 * 1000 * 24*7)), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy") + 7 );}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the shortest but it gives you greater flexibility for future changes

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const cols = [19, 21];
  if (sh.getName() == 'FW21') {
    if (~cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) && e.value == 'Done') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
    if (e.range.columnStart == 34 && e.value == 'OK Prod') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue("" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is showing error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Comment: I hope you realize that you can't call such a function without supplying the event object.  To debug such a script I find it easiest just to edit the page and see that it works correctly.  I use an occasional toast or Logger.log() to assist in the debugging. I've already run this on my account and it works fine